# Android SSH Example Code

Tags: android, ssh

I want to create an android activity for setting up an SSH Session with a remote device (through Wifi) and executing some linux commands on the remote device.  Anyone got a quick, short example for connecting, authenticating and sending remote commands using [Trilead](https://github.com/kruton/connectbot/tree/master/src/com/trilead/ssh2) libraries in Android ? Connectbot source (the only place to find the source for the unmaintained library) is quite vast and time consuming to go through if one is just trying to do a quick SSH Connection/ Command execution. I had found the sshJ library earlier, which had nicely documented examples and tips but unfortunately Android lacks some Java.Util classes required for sshJ.

I am looking for something in Trilead like (this is from the sshJ example I found earlier) :

```
final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
ssh.loadKnownHosts();

ssh.connect("localhost");
try {
    ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("user.name"));
    final Session session = ssh.startSession();
    try {
        final Command cmd = session.exec("ping -c 1 google.com");
        System.out.print(cmd.getOutputAsString());
        System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

} finally {
    ssh.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are okay with restricting your app to Android 2.3+ (Gingerbread), then you can use sshj. You will have to create the SSHClient object with this
[Config](https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/commit/c46dc913e8858d0164e0bf27a8e5b888dbb86740).

Comment: Cheers for the response. I would have to support at least 2.2.