# Android connectBOT :execute commands on a remote device

Tags: android, ssh

I'm tryning to configure my router from my android phone with SSH. Well i tryed the connectBOT, and it worked normaly like i want. But the code is too big and includes a lot of tasks that i don't need. 
I would like a simple android commands that open an SSH connection and execute some router configuration commands.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you searched on `android ssh library` on a search engine, what did you learn?

Comment: Thank you for replying.Actually i learned nothing ,i searched for a tutorial to learn and undestand how ssh works on android. But i'm just finding this code. I knwo it's running perfectly ,but i need to understand it before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android SSH Example Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879208/android-ssh-example-code) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14323661/simple-ssh-connect-with-jsch